# ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (error importing deepspeech python)

Tags: python, importerror, mozilla-deepspeech

I'm trying to run deepspeech's pretrained model using deepspeech's python module on a Windows Server 2016 but getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "c:\program files\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>
> "**main**", mod_spec)
>
> File "c:\program files\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>
> exec(code, run_globals)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\deepspeech.exe__main__.py", line 5, in
>
> File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\deepspeech__init__.py", line 23, in
>
> from deepspeech.impl import PrintVersions as printVersions
>
> File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\deepspeech\impl.py", line 13, in
>
> from ._impl import *
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.